# What is the load path for thrust in a rocket engine?

Tags: propulsion, engine-design, design, engineering, structural-design

This may be a duplicate of [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24586/where-does-the-thrust-act-in-a-rocket-engine-and-how-is-it-transferred-to-rocket) but I wasn't sure if I could hijack that one to clarify or regenerate interest there.

**What is the distribution of axial force in a combustion chamber?** My intuition is failing me.

What's the fraction transmitted to the face of the injector vs the nozzle? What's the distribution along the diverging section of the nozzle? The pressure is drops along the divergent section of the nozzle but the net velocity increases in the direction we care about. So is the force predominantly a reaction force to the pressure or a momentum transfer or are those the same thing?

An ideal answer would have two parts:

1. A rule of thumb (or state that there is no such rule and why)
2. An addition to the wikipedia CD nozzle diagram below showing the thrust component borne at that point with an explanation. (eg, "mean velocity/area" or something)

[image: wikipedia nozzle de laval diagram]

Comment: See this answer: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39939/6944 It may answer your question, but I am not 100% sure of that.

Comment: yup. that'll do it thanks

Comment: What's the best way to close the question as not needing an answer but leave it so that it shows up for search terms in the future?

Comment: Closing as a duplicate means the question still exists and shows up in search results, it just means that people can't add answers. That's probably the way to go.