What happens when the exhaust goes mach one
To create thrust and enough lift, you need a lot of mass thrown out at high velocities from a rocket engine. Most of the time this mass (exhaust) reaches over mach 1. I'm just curious whether this cause any difficulties of turbulence etc. If so, what are some difficulties and how must one solve them?

The flow through a properly designed converging-diverging nozzle goes supersonic at the throat.

Does it stay supersonic after that or does it go back to subsonic at any point?

Please read this answer https://space.stackexchange.com/a/18916/6944

"lift" typically refers to an aerodynamic force in aerospace systems. I can think of some weird rocket-blown-wing schemes where a rocket would be generating lift, but in the general case that is not what a rocket is doing

Rearch for "Mach Diamonds" to see what happens when Supersonic air hits "standing" air... :)
